# Oracle service Bus protocol transport in proxy

Tags: oracle, service, proxy, osb

I have some questions on the transport's tab on a proxy service.
I explain :  in my proxy service A, i have a publish component to call an asynchronous jms based service, called B.

The service B reads the message, sent by the publish component, in a jms queue. For example : jms://localhost:7001/interne.queue

the problem is the publish component never post the message on the queue if the protocol of the transport configuration on the service A is set to http. But if i change this setting to "local" all works fine.

Did any one can explain how this works please ?

Comment: What I understand you are saying is that you have two Proxies - A and B. A is http-based and B is jms based. And you can't publish from A to B. Is this correct? If yes, then how are you trying to publish from A to B?

Comment: Yes, that's  correct but the proxy B is called from the proxy A using the design component in eclipse called "publish". That let's you call a proxy based on JMS.

Answer (score 0):

The URL must have the following format:

```
jms://host:port/connection_factory/jndi_destination
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why a message from Proxy A (HTTP Proxy) would not be able to post a message to Proxy B (JMS Proxy). I have done hundreds and hundreds of such routings, and they have all worked fine. As suggested by user3414417 above, i would suggest you to check the JMS URL that you are using for posting the message to Proxy B over the JMS queue